# Showerror doesnt't want to appear, but the code seems no error

Tags: python, tkinter

I created an open file dialog app with Python with tkinter library:

```
class MainForm(Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent=parent
        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):
        #===============#
        self.frame1=Frame()
        self.frame1.pack(fill=X)
        
        self.lbl=Label(self.frame1,text="File Name")
        self.lbl.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
       
        #===============#
        self.frame2=Frame()
        self.frame2.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
        
        self.text1_Text=StringVar()
        self.text1=Entry(self.frame2,state=DISABLED,textvariable=self.text1_Text)
        self.text1.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=NW,fill=X,expand=True,padx=5,pady=5)
        
        #===============#
        
        self.frame3=Frame()
        self.frame3.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
           
        self.actBtn1=Button(self.frame3,text="Choose CSV File",command=lambda:[self.open_dialog(),self.open_csv_dataframe()])
        self.actBtn1.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)
        
        self.actBtn2=Button(self.frame3,text="Open",state=DISABLED,command=self.tes_dataframe)
        self.actBtn2.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5)
        
        #===============#
        self.frame4=Frame()
        self.frame4.pack(side=LEFT,anchor=N)
        
        self.lbl2=Label(self.frame4,text="Information")
        self.lbl2.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5)     
        
        self.helpBtn=Button(self.frame4,text="How To Use The Program")
        self.helpBtn.pack(side=LEFT,padx=5,pady=5,anchor=N)
        
        self.aboutBtn=Button(self.frame4,text="About Program")
        self.aboutBtn.pack(side=RIGHT,padx=5,pady=5,anchor=N)
        #===============#

    def open_dialog(self):
        global fileName
        try:
            self.fileName=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",filetypes=(("Comma-separated values","*.csv"),))
            self.text1_Text.set(self.fileName)     
        except FileNotFoundError:
            showerror("Error","The file is not selected yet")

    def open_csv_dataframe(self):
        if(self.actBtn2['state']==NORMAL):
            self.actBtn2['state']=DISABLED
        else:
            self.actBtn2['state']=NORMAL

    def tes_dataframe(self):
        global df
        data=pd.read_csv(self.text1.get(),sep=",")
        df=pd.DataFrame(data)
        root.destroy()      
    
def on_close():
    close = askokcancel("Close", "Do you want to exit?")
    if close:
        root.destroy()
        sys.exit(1)
     

if __name__=='__main__':
    root=Tk()
    app=MainForm(root)
    root.geometry("400x130+130+130")
    root.resizable(False,False)
    root.title("A Quite Complex File Dialog Form")
    root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",  on_close)
    root.mainloop()
```

The code that i wrote seems no error, but when i try execute this part:

```
    def open_dialog(self):
        global fileName
        try:
            self.fileName=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",filetypes=(("Comma-separated values","*.csv"),))
            self.text1_Text.set(self.fileName)     
        except FileNotFoundError:
            showerror("Error","The file is not selected yet")
```

I try to not choose a csv file, but no error message showed. It should be appeared like this:

[image: An error message should be appeared like this]

But it didn't appeared,

How to make it appeared, i tried many workaround but it came no result.

Comment: The `showerror` is called when `FileNotFoundError` is raised in the "try" block. In your case, this exception is never raised, at least not in this "try" block (because you don't open any files. All you do is just getting the filename of the file and inserting it to the `self.text1_Text` StringVar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to create errors. Many would prefer using the `raise` or `assert` for that.

since you have used except for FileNotFoundError you need to definitely use `raise` (errorName) and you have to use that when len(self.fileName)=0 that is when the file is not selected.

```
def open_dialog(self):
        global fileName
        try:
            self.fileName=filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",filetypes=(("Comma-separated values","*.csv"),))
            if len(self.fileName)==0:
                raise FileNotFoundError
            self.text1_Text.set(self.fileName)     
        except FileNotFoundError:
            showerror("Error","The file is not selected yet")
```

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly the problem is that if you force a file with different extension you want the program to tell you.So you could use endswith function, without raise an exception.

```
 def open_dialog(self):
    file = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/",filetypes=(("Comma-separated values","*.csv"),))

    if file.lower().endswith(('.csv',)):
        self.text1_Text.set(file)
    else:
        msg = "The file is not a csv file."
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(), msg, parent=self)
```

and move the control to the opening

```
def tes_dataframe(self):
    global df
    if self.text1.get():
        data=pd.read_csv(self.text1.get(),sep=",")
        df=pd.DataFrame(data)
        root.destroy()
    else:
        msg = "The file field is mandatory."
        messagebox.showwarning(self.master.title(), msg, parent=self)
```

finally...why so much global variables...you’re sure you need it?

Comment: much global variable you said? It's for my assignment tho, for opening the dataframe in console/terminal/CLI/whatever the name...... don't mind about it :))